# Control charts with rolling averages in R

Tags: r, moving-average

I am trying to create a Control charts with rolling averages in R that closely matches something like this. I am relatively new to R, and my grasp of all the available pages is not great yet.
[controlchart with moving average i'd like to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi2SW.jpg)
Can someone help me figure this out? Maybe point me to the right packages I should install and study? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to creating this type of chart myself.

One solution is the `qicharts` package.  Instead of calling the changes `rolling averages` or `stages` (the term Minitab uses), they call the changes `breaks`.

An example, from the documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts/qicharts.pdf):

```
# Create data frame with counts and sample sizes by week
d <- data.frame(week = seq.Date(as.Date('2013-08-04'),
                                by = 'week',
                                length = 36),
                y = c(rbinom(24, 20, 0.5), rbinom(12, 20, 0.8)),
                n = round(rnorm(36, 20, 2)))

# Break control chart before and after change
qic(y, n, x = week, data = d, chart = 'p', breaks = 24)
```

[image: First QI Charts example with breaks]

```
# Introduce extreme sample value and notes
d$a <- ''
d$a[30] <- 'Extreme value'
d$y[30] <- 1
qic(y, n, x = week, data = d, chart = 'p',
    breaks = 24,
    notes = a)
```

[image: Second QI Charts example with breaks and extreme value]

As a note, `qicharts` is being discontinued and users are being directed to use `qicharts2` instead. In the new version, `breaks` is replaced by `x.period` but there are no examples in the current documentation demonstrating its use.

Comment: Do you have any example code for this? The breaks and/or type of chart. A moving average chart seems to be a different chart type with different control limit calculations http://spcchartsonline.com/index.php/online-spc-control-charts/spc-control-charts/background-page-2/ma-moving-average-charts/

Comment: @Cassandra, the moving average chart you linked to is completely different from the "rolling averages" that were described in the image. Answer updated with example code directly from the literature (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qicharts/qicharts.pdf) and image added.